# Using Pest.rs, how can I specify that comments are to be anchored and whole line?

Tags: parsing, rust, peg, pest

[Exim uses a really awkward comment syntax,](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_exim_runtime_configuration_file.html)

> Blank lines in the file, and lines starting with a # character (ignoring leading white space) are treated as comments and are ignored. **Note: A `#` character other than at the beginning of a line is not treated specially, and does not introduce a comment.**

This means that,

```
# This is is a comment
This has no comments # at all
```

Is there a way to mirror this with Pest.rs? I've tried this,

```
COMMENT    = { "#" ~ (!NEWLINE ~ ANY)* ~ NEWLINE }
WHITESPACE = _{ " " }
main       = { SOI ~ ASCII_ALPHA* ~ EOI }
```

But, this will match on

```
MyText # Exim test this is not a comment
```

How can I anchor the comment to the left?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible with the default `COMMENT` expansion because it's expanded to [all instances of rule-concatenation with `~` except for the atomics.](https://docs.rs/pest_derive/2.1.0/pest_derive/#whitespace-and-comment). The following two lines are the same,

```
a = { b ~ c }
a = { b ~ WHITESPACE* ~ (COMMENT ~ WHITESPACE*)* ~ c }
```

This essentially means that if you were to use the `~` and `COMMENT` you'd have to restrict your rules to [atomic rules with `@` and `$`](https://docs.rs/pest_derive/2.1.0/pest_derive/#modifiers)

Instead of this, for a line-based grammar, I ended up refining this and not using the `COMMENT` macro. Instead defining my own macro, `_COMMENT` to avoid the normal expansion into non-atomic tokens,

```
WHITESPACE = _{ " " }
_COMMENT   = { "#" ~ (!NEWLINE ~ ANY)* ~ NEWLINE }
expr       = { ASCII_ALPHA+ }
stmt       = { expr ~ NEWLINE }
conf       = { SOI ~ (stmt | _COMMENT | NEWLINE)+ ~ EOI }
```

Notice here both `stmt` and `_COMMENT` are `NEWLINE` terminated, and the conf includes 1 or more of them.